# Reading and checking values from an array

Tags: java, arrays, file, directory

I want to read all the file names in a directory, which works so far except the checking for a specific file.
It is for a little statistic program that checks for "created", "deleted" and "edited" Entity files.

I want to search for the name of an Entity file 
(e.g. if the entity "aposting" exists, the value of "created" or "edited" would be increased by one, but 
if no entity with this name is in the directory, the "deleted" value would be increased by one).

my code:

```
package Statistik;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 *
 * @author KyoAkashi
 */
public class Statistik {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Namens Test");
        File[] FileNames = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < FileNames.length; i++) {
            if (FileNames[i].isFile()) {
                System.out.println("File " + FileNames[i].getName());
            } else if (FileNames[i].isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("Directory " + FileNames[i].getName());
            }
        }
        if(Arrays.asList(FileNames).contains("File 001.txt")){
            System.out.println("it exists");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("it doesn't exist");
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**
as from jon skeet requestet:

- i extended my question above
- my desired output is: "it exists" for a file in this directory
- i've also tried to make a new File and it didnt work as described above
- there is no error message just not the result it should be

Comment: "it wont work" is never enough information. Tell us exactly what you're seeing, what you expect to see, and what diagnostics you've performed to investigate.

Comment: But you should note that a `List<File>` will never contain a `String`...

Comment: @JonSkeet i've updated my question i hope it is now clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing File object with String which is invalid as `Arrays.asList(FileNames)` is going to return you list of File object. Probably what you want is to iterate over array and do equals on name of file:

```
boolean doesFileExists = false;
for (File file : FileNames) {
    if (file.getName().equals("File 001.txt")) {
        System.out.println("it exists");
        doesFileExists = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!doesFileExists) {
    System.out.println("it doesn't exist");
}
```

Comment: thank you but it still says that there is no file with this name, but i am 100% sure that it is!

Comment: This will print out "it doesn't exist" for *each* file that isn't the one the OP is looking for. It should print out "it exists" once, but it's still very misleading.

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.asList(FileNames)` returns a `List` of `File` objects, so you can't expect to find `String`s in it.
That's why `Arrays.asList(FileNames).contains("File 001.txt")` will always return false.

You'll have to create a list of actual file names in order for `.contains("File 001.txt")` to work.

You can do it with Java 8 Streams in a concise way:

```
Stream.of(FileNames).map(File::getName).anyMatch(s->s.contains("File 001.txt""))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
    File folder = new File("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Namens Test");
    File[] FileNames = folder.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < FileNames.length; i++) {
        if (FileNames[i].isFile()) {
            System.out.println("File " + FileNames[i].getName());
        } else if (FileNames[i].isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory " + FileNames[i].getName());
        }
    }
    File file = new File(folder.getPath() + "/File 001.txt");
    if (file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("it exists");
    } else {
        System.out.println("it doesn't exist");
    }
```